# What is the meaning of "Mushroom hunters do it in the dark"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-girl-with-all-the-gifts

In the film [The girl with all the gifts](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4547056/) there is a photo of 3 people (soldiers?) and handwritten text "Mushroom hunters do it in the dark".

What is the meaning of this phrase? How does it relate to the story of the film?

Edit: I would like to attach a screenshot but am not sure if that is allowed due to copyright etc.

Answer (score 5):

It's one of a million memes that all follow a similar pattern - you're meant to recognise the pattern and therefore that it's 'one of these memes'.
Very, very few of them are ever actually funny ;)

*[somebodies]* do it *[somehow]*

'do it' is always a double entendre:-

1. do their job
2. have sex

Carpenters do it with wood.
Window cleaners do it up a ladder.
Chess players do it on the table.
Farmers do it with sheep.
Nerds do it alone.
… ad nauseam.

Mushrooms grow in the dark, therefore mushroom hunters must hunt them… in the dark.

That simple.

*Late edit*
There may be actually an added implication [I don't know the movie so this is pure supposition]
People at the very bottom of any command ladder may consider themselves to be under-informed as to what is going on above them in the hierarchy.
There's another common meme, which may be salient.
"We're like mushrooms. Kept in the dark and fed on b***shit."